# How to list all saved custom filters in Control-M?

Tags: mainframe, control-m

Assume you created some, eg 3, custom filters saved with filter names A,B, C, using Control-M's ISPF client in zOS (mainframe). Using such custom filters, you can easily switch between the list of jobs to be shown in the *`Active Jobs File`*, using primary ISPF commands like:

- s A
- s B
- s C

If you only have like 3 such filters, and with names like A, B or C, it's a piece of cake to remember them all. However, if you have like a dozen of names, each with up to (say) a length 8 (XYZ10000, PQR123, etc), it's pretty much impossible to remember them all.

So is it somehow possible to bring up a list of all available filters (similar to an ISPF memberlist)? If not, where to go find all such filters that are defined, maybe in some ISPF profile dataset member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see a list of filters all you need to do is type `SHOW ?` in the command line and it will bring up a list of save filters.

Put an S beside the one you want to select it.

Comment: Merci for the "good start" (hence "accept now"), though at first I couldn't get it to work as you described. Refer to my own answer for the additional step (= PF8) I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Rather accidentally, I discovered the correct (and complete) answer to my own question ...

The previous answer is a good start, i.e. you need to issue command `show ?` (or just `s ?`). But in my case just typing `show ?` still didn't show the filters (like A, B or C as in my question). The additional clue to really get it to work, at least in my case, is that I also have to press the <kbd>PF8</kbd>-key to perform a *page down* in that pop-up window (shown after first typing `show ?`). And without pressing the <kbd>PF8</kbd>-key, I only see a list of (vanilla) filters that come with Control-M.